# unable to install pandas on a remote server

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, gcc

I tried to install pandas on a remote server, but I got the following error:

```
 pandas/_libs/tslibs/strptime.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such 
 file or directory #include "Python.h"
```

But, when I tried to locate, I was able to find it in :

```
python/Python-3.7.1/Include/Python.h
```

gcc couldn't recognize the path. How to solve this problem without using sudo install?

Comment: I assume you are using windows. Did you compile python ? Did you add it to your path ?

Comment: @OsumanAAA, it's linux.. look at `sudo install` and file structure. 

But your question about having python added to the system `PATH` is valid.

Comment: Have you tried using `pip install pandas` ?

https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/

Comment: Yes , I used pip install

Comment: can you show how you're trying to install and the entire error message you're getting?

Comment: Did you try installing `python3-dev` (or maybe `python3.7-dev` if it's available. You would need to use `sudo apt-get install` though.